# How to fix valgrind memory?

Tags: c, valgrind

So I have a structure and when I initiate one, I use malloc as so:

```
typedef struct node{ 
    void *value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

typedef struct QueueADT{
    int (*cmp)(const void*a, const void*b);
    struct node *front;
    int len;
    struct node *back;
} * QueueADT;




QueueADT que_create( int (*cmp)(const void*a, const void*b) ) {
    printf("%lu\n",sizeof(QueueADT));
    QueueADT q = (QueueADT)malloc(sizeof(QueueADT));
    if (q == NULL) {return NULL;}
    q->cmp = cmp;
    q->len = 0;
    return q;
}
```

valgrind spits out:

```
Invalid write of size 4
Address 0x5204490 is 8 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
```

write error pertains to q->len = 0;

I cannot tell what the problem is, am I allocating an incorrect amount of bytes?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], especially the declaration of QueueADT.

Comment: oops my bad, i should have done that

Comment: What's the definition of `QueueADT`?

Comment: Just added it in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `QueueADT` is a typedef for a pointer type.  That means `sizeof(QueueADT)` evaluates to the size of the pointer, not what it points to.  Since it seems that a pointer is 8 bytes on your system and that the struct in question is larger than that, you write past the end of allocated memory.

What you want instead is:

```
QueueADT q = malloc(sizeof(*q));
```

This allocates enough space for what `q` points to.  Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

It's also bad practice to hide a pointer behind a `typedef`, as it is not obvious that you're working with a pointer which can confuse the reader, and is probably what tripped you up in this case.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!  Nice assumption! It's all good now. also thanks for the explanation about typedef pointers, ill take that into consideration